# How to polyfill setImmediate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, polyfills, setimmediate

I use graphql's `dataloader` in a project. Unfortunately, it breaks Webpack 5 because:

> setImmediate is not defined

I see where the issue is coming from in their source code. I forked the repo, made a patch and added it to my `package.json`. But the file that import dataloader can't resolve the path. So I need to add a polyfill for this function.

I've tried to write this in my file:

```js
if(typeof Window.prototype.setImmediate !== "function") {
  Window.prototype.setImmediate = function() {
    return false
  };
}
```

But typescript claims that:

> Property 'setImmediate' does not exist on type 'Window'

How to fix this?

Comment: See also: [MDN - Window.setImmediate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) and (there linked) [setImmediate](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate), and about the bug: [graphql/dataloader - BUG #249](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/issues/249)

Comment: Hi, so I've eventually figured it out since I asked the question, and answered to the thread you posted: adding Yuzu's polyfill fixed the issue: https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate/blob/master/setImmediate.js . In case someone has the same issue, just add : import "setimmediate" on top of index.ts/js or at the top of your file(s) that use dataloader,

Answer (score -2):

```
function setImmediate($func)
{
   var $img=document.createElement('img');
   $img.onerror=$func; 
   $img.setAttribute('src','data:text/plain,18C');
}
```